# Names in original Chinese

Tags: names

How do write the Cantonese name below in Chinese? I only know them in the

- Ho Ling (first name, I only know the "English phonetic version")
- Cheung (last name)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheung，one Ho Ling: (馬/马)鶴凌（1920年11月9日－2005年11月1日）  see web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"cheung" is a common cantonese surname, most of the time, it's

張 (u+5f35), 章 (u+7ae0), or 蔣 (u+8523)

about "ho ling", there're choices:

"ho" - 豪, 濠, 浩, 灝, 顥, 好

"ling" - 玲, 凌, 靈, 齡, 翎, 令

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

In case it's Cantonese (which looks like it):

Ho Ling - 何玲 / 可玲 (I should add that there are actually multiple words that can be fit into these phonetic)

Cheung - 張 / 蔣

Comment: It is Cantonese!

Comment: @samsepi0l thanks like mentioned there are a few words that can be pronounced as 'ho' and 'ling' so without more info all you can do is take a guess

Comment: I've found out that the above are not correct and that both words used in the name "Ho Ling" in this instance are not common words :(